# Access header when header name has - in it plumber R

Tags: r, plumber

I am trying to pass header "X-Name" from postman then access it from API which is build using Plumber R.

However, I am not able to access it. using following code,

`req$HTTP_X-NAME`,  then i am getting following error.

> Error in (function (id, time_frame, req, res) : object 'name' not
>   found\n"

If I use following code, I get NULL values,

```
req$HTTP_X_NAME
```

or

```
req[["HTTP_X-NAME"]
```

or

```
req[["HTTP_X-Name"]
```

Following is my code:

```
#* @get /
healthCheck <- function(){
  print("It's Running")
}

#* @param id:int Random Number
#* @post /test/values
#* @get /test/values
test <- function(id, req, res){
  print(req[["HTTP_X-Name"]])
  return(req[["HTTP_X-Name"]])
}
```

Comment: What about `req[["HTTP_X-NAME"]]`? It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MrFlick That and the column name between back ticks. (If I post it here the SO editor will think that I'm posting code.)